# VBA - error in .NumberFormat for date

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is that the format of my column `DATE` is `Mar 16 2016 3:19PM`. The format that I need for my code to run is `3/16/2016` and now I'm try to convert it. This is the error I get with using my code:

> Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

this is the line that i got the error

```
data = Intersect(Sheet2.Columns("O"), Sheet2.UsedRange).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub Selection()

Dim file2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet, data(), i&

    Set Sheet2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)

    ' load the data from column O
    data = Intersect(Sheet2.Columns("O"), Sheet2.UsedRange).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    'set the title
    data(1, 1) = "Month"
    ' extract the month
    For i = 2 To UBound(data)
    If VarType(data(i, 1)) = vbDate Then
      data(i, 1) = Month(data(i, 1))
    End If
  Next

  ' write the data back to the sheet
  Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns(Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1) = data

End Sub
```

I've tried using:

`outputWksht.Columns(24).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"`

and

`Cells(1, 1).Value = Format(StartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

There are no errors but its not working, I wonder why??

Comment: Do you have a merged cell in column "O" ?

Comment: @florentbr yes thats where my column date is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
  For i = 2 To UBound(data)
  If VarType(data(i, 1)) = vbDate Then
    data(i, 1) = Month(data(i, 1))
  End If
Next
```

to this:

```
For i = 2 To UBound(data)
  data(i, 1) = Month(CDate(data(i, 1)))
Next i
```

Comment: wow its now working! thanks your @vegard so my code is for mm/dd/yyyy format and yours is Mar 16 2016 3:19PM

Comment: My code fixes a possible mismatch and makes it easier to apply the correct number format by forcing the value to become a `Date` type. You should be able to apply whatever format you want to it once it is being put on the sheet.

Comment: coz i tried mm/dd/yyyy and i got an error type mismatch but now that i re-run it again its now working, but in the output there is something wrong in the output.. i have 19 rows i used march so the value will be 3 all 19 rows are 3 but there is row 20 and the value is 12

Comment: You have to show us the original data for the cell that is going wrong and the result of the procedure.

Comment: i've tried it on other file its working, the problem is the file that i'm using i think it has to do with the format

Comment: is it possible to upload my file here..?

Comment: No. But I doubt the whole file is necessary - you can just paste the original and resulting data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106552/discussion-between-7a65726f-and-vegard).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
Cells(1, 5).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: i tried it but its not working, thanks for answer tho

Comment: I just already tried it and it works. Can you describe it more? Which is your input, how looks like result,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  Dim data As Range
  Set data = Intersect(Sheet2.Columns("O"), Sheet2.UsedRange)
  data.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: i already declared data, 
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet, data(), i&

Comment: Where are you stuck at BTW.

Comment: i want to return month value from column O which contains date but what i getting is the exact value from column O